# std::reduce with multiple 3d unordered_maps ( summing values for identical keys)

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, reduce, unordered-map

I have a 16 thread generating their outputs to 3d unordered_maps with the following signature

`std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, int>>> parameter_space;`

What I am trying to do is to merge all those 16 3d unordered_maps into 1. As you can imagine this is incredibly slow.

I was Then drawn to `std::accumulate` followed by `std::reduce`.

The problem is the syntax is very complex (at least for me).

I was wondering if someone here could point me in the right direction.

I unsuccessfully tried to create the syntax for std::reduce or std::accumulate for multiple 3d unordered_maps

Comment: Please show an example of input and output. It's not entirely clear what you mean by merging all the maps into one.

Comment: "As you can imagine this is incredibly slow." Don't do prepremature optimization. Don't imagine. Write the code, measure, then you can still improve it. If you have no code then there is nothing to be made faster

Comment: Could you please clarify your questions? You can merge maps using [merge()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge). But, be careful with identical keys, since these won't be merged. For the second part of your question, you need to define what's the sum of two 2d maps, or did you mean something else going through all 3d elements and add the elements with the same keys? If this is the case using merge could help you in your process.

Comment: if you need help with code you should post a [mcve]

Comment: It is possible (and feels likely) that such map of maps of maps is pessimal data structure for your whole problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to accumulate the maps would be something like this:

```
using my_map = std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, int>>>;

void accumulate(my_map& accu,const my_map& add) {
    for (const auto& mapmap : add) {
         const auto& mapmapkey = mapmap.first;
         for (const auto& map : mapmap) {
             const auto& mapkey = map.first;
             for (const auto& element : map) {
                const auto& key = element.first;
                accu[mapmapkey][mapkey][key] += element.second;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

This can be called in a loop for all maps to be accumulated.

You might think that deep nesting of loops is what makes this slow, though that deep nesting is merely a consequence of the container you are using. It iterates all elements in `add` not more not less.

I suggest to try a `std::unordered_map< std::tuple<int,int,int>, int>` rather than the deeply nested map you are using currently. Not for performance but for clarity and readability of the code. Or even better use a custom structure as key where you can give the `int`s a proper name.

For performance you need to measure. Standard algorithms are usually not slower than handwritten loops, but there is also no reason to expect them to be faster. They are not magic. Their main advantage is not speed, but expressiveness. When you have problems to express an algorithm in terms of standard algorithms then trying hard to use them has no inherent advantage. You can always write the code without standard algorithms and only later consider to refactor it. If the handwritten loop is too slow then the algorithm can be expected to be slow too.